# Почему код работает неверно, если else стоит под if, но если сдвинуть его на одну табуляцию влево, то всё работает исправно?

Tags: python

Пытался сделать вывод простых чисел в диапазоне. Так выглядит мой изначальный код, он выводит мне набор дублирующихся чисел:

```
for number in range(1, 100): 
    if number > 1: 
        for i in range(2, number): 
            if(number % i) == 0: 
                break 
            else: 
                print(number)
```

Но если написать else под for, то всё работает исправно и он выводит простые числа в нужном диапазоне:

```
for number in range(1, 100): 
    if number > 1: 
        for i in range(2, number): 
            if(number % i) == 0: 
                break 
        else: 
            print(number)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К чему во втором случае относится `else`? К `for`, и срабатывает в том случае, если цикл не был прерван `break`, т.е. ни одно число не было делителем `number`. Всё правильно, значит `number` - простое. Такое использование `else` - специфично для Python (может, и ещё где есть).

В первом же случае `else` относится к `if`, и срабатывает на первом числе, не являющемся делителем `number` (9 не делится на 2? тут же выводим 9)  - но ведь у него могут быть другие делители.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не понимаете, как работает код, который выдаёт правильный результат. И это закономерно. Дело в том, что хотя синтаксически это и выгладит правильно, но смысл "закопан" довольно глубоко. Я не буду сейчас всё это подробно расписывать, просто покажу, как эта задача должна решаться "обычным" образом:

```
for number in range(1, 100): 
    if number > 1: 
        Simpl = True 
        for i in range(2, number):
            if(number % i) == 0:
                Simpl = False
                break
                 
        if Simpl: 
            print(number)
```

Так гораздо более полнятно.